# MVC3 Custom routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I developed a website with MVC and I have a little problem on how link addresses appears in the address bar.
When I open the website, I have to log on first; after I log on into the account, the home page appear, but in the browser address bar I still have

```
http://localhost:1413/Account/LogOn
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:1413/Home
```

Also, after I log out, I am redirected to the log in page, but in the address bar it appears

```
http://localhost:1413/Account/LogOn
```

I would like to be just

```
http://localhost:1413/Account/LogOff
```

My Global.asx code

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );           
    }
```

I used this type of redirection, but the result is the same:

```
public ActionResult LogOn()
    {
        if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Your routes look fine. I suspect the issue is with your redirect logic, or with your links

Answer (score 1):

you need to use redirect action to home page like this

```
RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller")
```

so when user has been authenticated you need to redirect the user to the particular controller.

Same goes for the when user logged off

Comment: That's how it is. Thank you.

Comment: I used this type of redirection, but the result is the same: `public ActionResult LogOn()
        {
            if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            return View();
        }`

Comment: you dont have use  return View(); when you have already specified the  return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, your problem is not the routing cause your routing is working fine. Your problem is that you work in the controller Account. That's why account always appears in you url. If you want to get this:

```
http://localhost:1413/Home
```

You must link to a controller which you called HomeController.cs

I hope you understand what i tried to explain.

Maybe this can help you more:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/190267/Controllers-and-Routers-in-ASP-NET-MVC-3